# Make an ajax request to google calendar api

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-api

I'm trying to make an ajax request to google calendar API, but something goes wrong. 
Here I have very simple code, but I don't understand why it is not working.

```
var mykey = 'my server key'; // I am using here server key(which I created in credentials in console.developers.google.com) Maybe I am using wrong version?! I've tried browser key, but it didn't help me.

var calendarid = 'my client_id'; // here I am using VALID clientId, which I created in my project in developer console. Below this code I attached screen.

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: encodeURI('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/' + calendarid+ '/events?key=' + mykey),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        //console.log('Nice!')
    },
    error: function (response) {
        //console.log('Bad!')
    }
});
```

I always have error 404 (OK) in browser console. Any help will be appreciated!

[Here is screenshot](http://take.ms/aNpNg) for my ClientID.

Comment: AJAX cross domain / origin is not ok. Should do the call from the server. Or this might work but never tested: http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use OAuth to show the sign in prompt and obtain an access token before you can contact the Calendar API. The easiest way do this is with the [Google API JavaScript Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/). [See this example](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js#step_2_set_up_the_sample).